# Как правильно расставить запятые в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Подскажите, как правильно расставить запятые в следующем предложении:

> Возмущаясь при этом без единой на то причины.

Comment: Возмущаясь зря, - достаточно. Либо: возмущаясь, не имея на то причин, - деепричастие обособляется.

Comment: Касательно же "Возмущаясь при этом без единой на то причины", дело в том, что тут по виду один деепричастный оборот и запятых не нужно, вот только предложение только из деепричастного оборота состоять не может. Деепричастный оборот должен быть чему-то противопоставлен, либо привязан к какому-то понятию.

Comment: Это не предложение, а деепричастный оборот, запятые там не нужны. А проверить стилистику  при построении оборота можно только при наличии самого предложения.